# How can you filter out other languages Taxonomy Terms from an exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I am working on a View for a content type which has a Taxonomy Term field.  The vocabulary is setup with the Translation mode 'Translate'.  The terms have all been translated so that the terms explicitly set Language (currently English and Spanish).  The View has an exposed filter for this field and its showing both languages terms.  How can I configure Drupal to only show the taxonomy terms for the current users language?

[image]

Relevant installed modules: Internationalization (i18n), Views translation (i18nviews), Taxonomy translation

I've read a lot of forums about how to get more languages terms to show, just not how to filter them out when you don't want to show them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long time ago but I leave my comment here for anyone who came across this from Google. 
If you have installed "`i18nviews"` module, then you need to enable `Multilingual select (i18n_select)` module as well and your list will be filtered out based on the selected language.

Comment: That did it, enabling that module separated the options just fine. Thanks for taking the time to leave this answer.